# Class 'bool' has no instance method '-'. Receiver: true Tried calling: -(false)

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to use `TweenAnimationBuilder<bool>` but I really don't know what was the problem even I had the exception logs. I tired googling before posting this question, but it was of no help.

**Exception:**

```
Class 'bool' has no instance method '-'.
Receiver: true
Tried calling: -(false)
The relevant error-causing widget was TweenAnimationBuilder<bool>
```

**Code:**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder<bool>(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      tween: Tween<bool>(begin: false, end: true),
      builder: (BuildContext context, bool tween, Widget child) {
        print(tween.toString());
        return Visibility(visible: showNavBar, child: child);
      },
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Colors.green,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.explore), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.library_books), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: "Home")
        ],
        onTap: (index) {},
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TweenAnimationBuilder<bool>` attempts to use a `Tween<bool>`, but `Tween<T>` cannot be used with `bool`.  From the [`Tween`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Tween-class.html) documentation:

> ### Types with special considerations
>
> ...
>
> Types that define `+` and `-` operators to combine values (`T + T → T` and `T - T → T`) and an `*` operator to scale by multiplying with a double (`T * double → T`) can be directly used with `Tween<T>`.

`bool` does not provide `+`, `-`, and `*` operators.